# Why is this program telling me invalid parameter was passed?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, 2d-vector

Honestly I don't even know what I am trying to do as of now. But I can't go further until I get this function to work, and it throws that exception each time, what is going wrong? The exception is "Unhandled exception at 0x0F61CAB6 (ucrtbased.dll) in CS 330 19S, P1, Calvert, Program 1.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Kinematic {
    vector<vector<float>> position;
    float orientation;
    vector<vector<float>> velocity;
    float rotation;
};

struct StreeringOutput {
    vector<vector<float>> linear;
    float angular;
};

void update(StreeringOutput steering, float time, Kinematic k) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
        {
            k.position[i][j] += k.velocity[i][j] * time + 
                           0.5*steering.linear[i][j] * time*time;
                           //the above command is where it throws the exception
            k.velocity[i][j] += steering.linear[i][j] * time;
        }
    }
    k.orientation += k.rotation*time + 0.5*steering.angular*time*time;
    k.rotation = steering.angular*time;

}


int main()
{
    int test;
    Kinematic kin;
    StreeringOutput steering;
    float time = 0.0;

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Output.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        update(steering, time, kin);
        time += 0.5;
    }
    cin >> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing the problem as required here please.

Comment: You do not appear to have ever allocated space in your `vector`s, so indexing into them is an illegal operation. Use a debugger to investigate.

Comment: Use `steering.at(i).at(j)` instead, and then fix the exceptions.

Comment: Maybe the real code has been simplified away, but updating the by-value `k`parameter is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the program starts, you create the objects:

```
Kinematic kin;
StreeringOutput steering;
```

This is called **default-initialization**, i.e. all members are initialized to the **default value**. For `vector`, it is the empty state.

But `update` does these things:

```
// i and j can be as large as 99
k.position[i][j]
k.velocity[i][j]
steering.linear[i][j]
```

But `position`, etc. are empty! `vector`s cannot automatically grow to fit your needs. You are indexing **out-of-bound**, which is undefined behavior.

You should initialize the vectors properly to ensure there are actually 100 elements:

```
Kinematic kin;
kin.position.assign(100, vector<float>(100));
// same for others
```